# how do i edit other users profile on django

Tags: python, django

i have two separate users, i want some users to be able to modify other users profile. The problem i am facing now is how to get the users id. i have a 2 views involved in this. The profile view, the edit profile view. i tried to wrap the entire profile html in a form, i am not sure that will work.
most of the examples only show how to edit current(logged in) user's profile.

the link to a specific users profile (http://127.0.0.1:8000/dashboard/profile/dfrtgy-ehehh/16)
the profile page has a link to the edit profile page.

profile html

```
   <li>
                        <a href="{% url 'editprofile' %}"><img class="nav-items" src="{% static 'images/lab.svg'%}" alt=""><span>Edit profile</span>
                        </a>
                    </li>
```

views.py

```
def edit_profile(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        profile = Profile.objects.get(pk=pk)
        form = EditProfileForm(request.POST, instance=request.user.profile)

        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return redirect(f'/dashboard/profile/{request.user.profile.slug}/{request.user.pk}')
    else:
       
        form = EditProfileForm(instance=request.user.profile)
        args = {'form': form}
        return render(request, 'core/editprofile.html', args)

def profile(request, slug, pk):
    profil = Profile.objects.get(slug=slug)
    profile = Profile.objects.get(pk=pk)
    context = {'profile': profile, 'profil': profil}
    return render(request, 'dashboard/profile.html', context)
```

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', dashboard, name='dashboard'),
    path('profile/', profile, name='profile'),
    path('profile/<str:slug>/<int:pk>', profile, name='profilepk'),
    path('edit_profile/', edit_profile, name='editprofile'),
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm guessing you're trying to edit the user who's profile you're on. You might want to try and fetch the current user's (the user who's profile you're on) ID and pass it on the editprofile URL like this:

```
<li>
<a href="{% url 'editprofile' profile.user.id %}"><img class="nav-items" src="{% static 'images/lab.svg'%}" alt=""><span>Edit profile</span>
</a>
</li>
```

and then pass it with url:

```
 path('edit_profile/<int:id>/', edit_profile, name='editprofile'),
```

and on your editprofile view, do this:

```
    from django.shortcuts import render, redirect, get_object_or_404

def edit_profile(request,id):
    profile = Profile.objects.get(user_id=id)
    user = get_object_or_404(Profile, pk=id, user=profile.user.id)
    if request.method == 'POST':
       
        form = EditProfileForm(request.POST, instance=profile)

        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return redirect(f'/dashboard/profile/{profile.user.slug}/{profile.user.pk}')
        else:
            return HttpResponse('Could not save')

    else:
       
        form = EditProfileForm(instance=user)
        args = {'form': form}
        return render(request, 'core/editprofile.html', args)
```

Hope this helps! (:

Comment: it doent''t work, i am getting ```edit_profile() got an unexpected keyword argument 'id'```

Comment: I think editprofile view is to save your profile right?

Comment: no, edit profile view is to edit other users profile

Comment: Just change the user_id in the argument to id and you'll be good to go! (:

Comment: i fixed some problems with it. The new problem i am facing is that the form does not save. i will create a new question thanks for your assistance